# Given two finite point sets $X,Y$, how to efficiently calculate the projection of $conv(X),conv(Y)$ onto their closest points?

Tags: optimization, convex-geometry, convex-hulls

Let's say we're given two sets of points, $X:=(x_i)_{i\in k_1},Y:=(y_i)_{i\in k_2}\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n$ and their convex hulls $conv(X),conv(Y)$.

Let's assume $conv(X),conv(Y)$ are disjunct. We want to find 
$x\in conv(X),y\in conv(Y)$ so that the euclidian distance $d(x,y)$ is minimal.

One possible phrasing of this problem as optimization problem would be:
$$
\min_{\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_{k_1},\mu_1,\ldots,\mu_{k_2}\in\mathbb{R}}{d}\left(\sum_{i=1}^{k_1}\lambda_ix_i,\sum_{i=1}^{k_2}\mu_iy_i\right) $$,
under the constraints
$$ \begin{align*}
 \sum_{i=1}^{k}\lambda_i&=1&\\
  \sum_{i=1}^{k_2}\mu_i&=1 &\\
  \lambda_i&\geq0     &, i=1,..,k_1\\
  \mu_i&\geq0   &, i=1,\ldots,k_2\\
\end{align*}$$

I'm wondering whether there's an easier formulation of this problem which doesn't rely on quadratic optimization.

Comment: A linear problem would always have support points as the extrema, but should be obvious that this does not have to be true. Consider a tetrahedron with one of its vetices point to the center of a face on a cube. The shortest distance between them is from the vertex to the face center. Such an answer can never come out of a linear optimization. So there is no way to turn this problem into a linear optimization. You can get rid of the square root by minimizing the distance squared, which occurs at the same points.

Comment: @PaulSinclair By support points, you mean the edges of our convex hull, i.e. the initial points, correct?

Comment: I mean the set of points it is the convex hull of. the points in $X$ or $Y$. Every vertex of the convex hull will be among these support points - though not all support points are necessarily vertices (the non-vertex support points could be dropped from the set without changing the convex hull). But actually, it is the vertices that will be the unique extrema of any linear optimization problem. Any other boundary point can be extrema only if the entire hyper-face it is on is equally extreme.

Comment: @PaulSinclair Ah, I understand. I had completely forgotten to take  the geometric aspects of a linear problem into account. That's a nice and easy counter-example you gave there!

Answer (score 0):

An iterative algorithm for determining a pair of closest points of two disjunct convex hulls running in linear time can be given as a variant of The Gilbert-Johnson-Keerthi Distance Algorithm.